# Draw bigger points on a Graph with core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

In my iOS app I would like to mark special points of a function, like the intersection of the curve with the x and y axis. Is this possible with core plot?

Answer (score 1):

The datasource can provide different plot symbols for each data point using the [`-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:`](https://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_scatter_plot_data_source-p.html#a38cd4ee184405fb9960d60aa99f34922) method. You can also use a second scatter plot with no data line that contains only the points you want to highlight.

Comment: It works, thank you very much.